# Count pending request in WCF serviceThrottling

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, throttling

I have developed one WCF Service application which is self hosted due to some windows access problem. This application has to do one operation at a time so I have implemented WCF serviceThrottling setting:

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentInstances="1" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
```

Now, I need to count the number of pending user request. I did some search but could not find any reliable solution that can answer my question. Is there any method that can count the number of pending request in the WCF host service.